# Handling textures correctly

Tags: java, opengl, rajawali

I got a texture mapped to a sphere and when i tilt my device, another texture should be mapped to the sphere and the previous one should be deleted from memory.

```
//Handles the texture
currentSphereTexture = new Texture("sphereTexture", R.drawable.rsz_01);
        TextureManager.getInstance().addTexture(currentSphereTexture);

//Creation of a sphere geometry
currentSphereMaterial = new Material();
currentSphereMaterial.addTexture(currentSphereTexture);
currentSphereMaterial.setColorInfluence(0);

//Create the mesh (actual object)
currentSphere.setMaterial(currentSphereMaterial);
```

And I update the sphere with the new texture:

```
currentSphereMaterial.addTexture(texture);
currentSphereMaterial.removeTexture(currentSphereTexture);
```

But in the end it still results to an Out Of Memory exception. How can i release the textures correctly so it only project one texture at the time on the sphere?

Comment: are you using v0.9 tag of rajawali ?

Comment: No i'm not. Is there a lot of difference between the master an v0.9?

Comment: Rajawali suggest v0.9 for  production use. I suggest a) read bitmap in your code with `options.inScaled = false;`, and pass that Bitmap to rajawali b) or else if you prefer to pass resource id to Rajawali, then use the method with `recycle` parameter for creating texture so that Bitmap created by rajawali will by recycled as early as possible.